# changing redirect: while returning modelandview

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

how to remove context path from redirect: while returning modelandview.

Mycurrent path looks like-- localhost.com:8080/main
where /main is my context path.

I want to redirect to localhost.com:8080/new
while returning modelandview  using redirect:

or, You can say I want to one level up in my path.

NOTE: "localhost.com:8080" is environment specific so it changes accordingly.

my code:
Here this is part of controller class with request mapping value= /main.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{responsePath:[\\w-]+}" + UNCOMPR_SUFFIX + ".xml"    //UNCOMPR_SUFFIX =-uncompressed
            + APACHE_URL_SUFFIX_FILTER, method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView getUncompressed(//
        @ModelAttribute(MODEL_NAME) final TaskModel model, //
        @PathVariable(value = "responsePath") final String responsePath) {

    final WebserviceLog task =               this.getServiceFacade().getSystemServices().getWebserviceLogService()
                    .getByResponsePath(responsePath + FILE_SUFFIX_XML);

    byte[] uncompressed = this.getServiceFacade().getSystemServices().getWebserviceLogService()
                .getUncompressedResponse(task.getId());


    } catch (Exception exception) {
         return new ModelAndView(//
                    String.format("redirect:/new/%s", responsePath));

}
```

So, here instead of going to localhost:8080/main/new/xyz.xml
I want to go to localhost:8080/new/xyz.xml.

Comment: Post some code!

Comment: you're using spring or spring boot ?

Comment: You cant change the context path for particular url, but you can change it for whole application in spring boot, by setting the **server.servlet.contextPath** value in application.properties file like `server.servlet.contextPath=/`

Comment: Actually for other env. its fetching a file at one level above path. In my case /main showed be removed while returning to get that file.